# How to get the source ip address of DDP call by a Java client in Meteor

Tags: java, meteor, ddp

I call a meteor server function from a java client via ddp, how to get the ip of the java server in meteor in order to restrict the access ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a Meteor method, you could access client information through `this.connection` object. The detail of this object is specified [here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#Meteor-onConnection). To get IP of client you could do:

```
Meteor.methods({
  test() {
    const ip = this.connection.clientAddress;
  }
});
```

Note that if your server is run behind proxies, you will need to set the `HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT` environment variable to the number of proxies in front of your server.